# How to get custom post type with dynamic ID

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, get-post

I want to show a custom post type chosen from the meta box dropdown list but i am getting this error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\affiliator\footer.php on line 20`
Here is my code:

```
$get_footer = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'af_choose_layout', true );

if( !empty( $get_footer ) ){
      $footer = get_post( $get_footer  );
      echo apply_filters('the_content',$footer->post_content);
}
```

So i just want to get the id of the custom post that can be usable for `get_post(some id here...)`. Please help me to fix this

Comment: The `get_the_id()` function would return whatever the current post is. Maybe `var_dump( $get_footer )` and ensure that it holds the expected value.

Comment: I have already checked `$get_footer` and it works fine, now i am going to try `get_the_id()`.

Comment: No luck with `get_the_id()`.

Comment: Maybe edit your question with all the details you currently have. For example, what specifically do you mean "no luck" with that function? Does it not return the right value?

Comment: Receiving no value with that even no error is showing.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee i only want my custom post type id so i can put in the `get_footer()`